# Which options should I enable in conanfile.txt to use with QML/ QtQuick?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2, conan

I try to set up an environment with conan using qt/5.15.2@bincrafters/stable.
Getting the following error when running the code

```
"main.qml:1:1: module "QtQuick" is not installed"
```

Need to find out how to install QML correctly with Conan.

Comment: do you get it on the runtime? Did you deploy your application with qt tools?

Comment: It was runtime. I managed to solve it. The problem must have been caused because I missed 'qt:qtdeclarative=True' to add in options of conanfile.txt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you found out yourself for QtQuick you need at least `qtdeclarative=True`, you can also add these options for the controls library:

```
qtquickcontrols=True  # for QQC1
qtquickcontrols2=True # for QQC2
```

On Linux, I've also found adding these modules to be useful:

```
config=-xcb
qttools=True
qttranslations=True
qtvirtualkeyboard=True
qtx11extras=True
qtsvg=True
```